# Regarding the error handling for ya-csv

Tags: node.js, csv

I am trying to do error handling in my nodejs project.The project is something like i have a page where i insert the csv; and after submitting it through the page;It leads to a page it will be rendered.To achieve this i am using 'ya-csv' parser like below.

var reader = yaCSV.createCsvFileReader(req.files.fileCSV.path, {
            'separator' : ',',
            'quote' : '"',
            'escape' : '"'
        });
where "req.files.fileCSV.path" represents the path of the file from where it has to extract the  data.

I want to do the error handling for it.I can not really think of handling it when user enter no file or some wrong file.How can i handle it with this.

-Learner

Answer (score 1):

I've done some investigating regarding this as I came across this issue as well.
They don't show this in the documentation, but you can attach a error handling function, and in the handler do what you need to do, then resolve.

```js
yaCSV.addListener('error', (err) => {
    console.error(`Error parsing ${path}: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
    resolve or reject
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i am able to solve my problem.It was a problem because of the asynchronous behaviour of the ya-CSV api i.e "yaCSV.createCsvFileReader".If i enter a wrong CSV or dont enter any file name to parse then it was throwing an error.Even though I was putting the code inside the try- catch but still i was getting the error as after calling the "createCsvFileReader"(which returns the result asynchronous) so my code will continue executing.So when the error is occurring my code for handling it, has already been executed.So to handle it,'ya-csv' provide an listener where you can put your call back method to handle it.